# Fly in my house (Santa Clara County, California)

Tags: pest-control, insect

Not exactly a DIY question. But I have recently noticed a lot of flies in my house. They look like mostly horse flies (completely black in color).

I have used electric impulse swing racquet to kill few of them, but after i kill 4-5 and area looks clear I see another 4-5 in some time (around an hour or so). so far within last 30 hours I might have killed around 60 flies in multiple batches of 5-7 flies at a time.

It has been raining here in Santa Clara County, California from past couple of weeks and was wondering if it can be the reason. To add to it I had been away and my house was closed for close to 1.5 months but there was no trash/food which was in open.

I also noticed similar fly insects in a unit close by my place.

So am wondering if its a seasonal thing (seeing it for the first time here in last 4 years).

Also if someone can recommend how to get rid of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider getting some fly paper. It is a sticky sheet that has an odor that attracts flies and they get stuck on when they land on it. Very efficient.

There are also fly sticker products that are a strip of the extremely sticky material that pulls out of a small round paper canister. These come with either a loop on the end for hanging or an integrated thumb tack so you can hang them from the ceiling in the room where the flies are most apt to congregate.

Growing up on a mid-west dairy farm in the '60s it was a common problem to have flies in the farm house so there was almost always a fly sticker hanging from the light fixture in the center of the kitchen dining area. Once the flies land on the sticky paper they may buzz for a short time before they give up and succumb to their fate.

Comment: I also find the sticky fly strips the least expensive way to deal with them once they are inside. I did not think the plastic bag with water and a couple of pennies above the door would do any good but they do help keep the flys from coming in through the door, we have horses our back slider used to be covered with flys after putting up the bag of water with a couple of pennies no flys stay on the door now. We have spent a lon on fly eating bugs and try everything but the sticky strips although ugly are cheap and work.+